# Executing cmd commands with Java

Tags: java, cmd, tshark

I am trying to run 2 `cmd` commands in order to start `tshark` from `cmd`.
Can you please help me understand why this code does not work?

```
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe");

    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));
    writer.write("cd C:/Program Files/Wireshark");
    writer.flush();

    writer.write("tshark.exe -i 1 -p -a duration:60 -w C:/Users/User/Desktop/AutomatedProtocolsPcapsCreator/CreatedPcaps/fileName.pcap");
    writer.flush();
```

Comment: Does it work with only one of the commands?

Comment: Can you post the error that you get?

Comment: Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start"); is the right way to invoke cmd

Comment: Why do you want to run `tshark` in a `cmd`? Is it to get the output of `tshark`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ProcessBuilder`. There are some gotchas around capturing console output, but otherwise I was very happy with this API.

```
new ProcessBuilder("tshark.exe", "-i",  "1", "-p", "-a", "duration:60", "-w",
  "C:/Users/User/Desktop/AutomatedProtocolsPcapsCreator/CreatedPcaps/fileName.pcap")
     .start()
```

Comment: still doesn't work, i get CreateProcess error=2 error.

Comment: It tries to tell you this info: "The system cannot find the file specified". You need to specify correct path to `tshark.exe`. You can even use absolute path.

Comment: it's probably because tshark.exe is not located in current directory seaprate process is executed in. You can use `ProcessBuilder.setDirectory()` or use absolute path.